# NagiosQL Installation: Checking requirements. Write test on settings file (config/settings.php): failed

Tags: oracle-linux, nagios

I've installed NagiosQL mostly following [this tutorial](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-nagiosql-on-centos).

On the Checking requirements step I've got failed state for Write test on settings file (config/settings.php):
[image: Image with failed state for Write test on settings directory (config/)]

How to make nagios pass Write test on settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how it was installed Nagios could be in /etc/nagios or /usr/local/nagios.

Additional files can be found at "/usr/lib64/nagios/"

The HTML files where I think this file is located is at "/usr/share/nagios/"

Comment: I've just installed nagios-core on other OL7 machine and then followed tutorial mentioned and now it shows OK. But before connection lost to previous machine, there's also OK status appeared. I've added nagios and nagiosql directories with config directory inside to path: /usr/share/nagios/etc/ making them writable for apache:nagios (user:group). So, maybe it is /usr/share/nagios/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to install nagiosql on other system and files/directories permissions' changing did not help. I've tried other tutorials and they did not help until I've tried [this tutorial](https://ahmermansoor.blogspot.com/2019/02/install-nagiosql-nagios-configurator-centos-7.html). It did not help firstly. But I was following instructions. I removed my previous nagiosql folder and started again using new tutorial. I've launched `# restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/nagiosql/` command.

It displayed:

> restorecon reset /var/www/html/nagiosql/admin/settings.php context
>   unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0

Googling for this text I've understood that I have to disable SELinux.

```
# sestatus
# setenforce 0
# vi /etc/selinux/config
...
SELINUX=disabled
...
```

After SELinux disabling `# restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/nagiosql/` command displayed no messages and I've got:

> Write test on settings directory (config/): OK